# Парсинг xml

Tags: android, java

Привет всем. Столкнулся с проблемой парсинга xml. Предположим есть вид xml:

```
 <item>
  <title>Текст информации</title>
  <desc>Текст информации</desc>
 </item>
```

Есть код, который успешно обрабатывает такую xml:

```
public class Parser {

Item objItem;
List<Item> listArray;

public List<Item> getData(String url) {

    try {

        listArray = new ArrayList<Item>();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream(),"UTF-8");
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                objItem = new Item();

                objItem.setTitle(getTagValue("title", eElement));
                objItem.setDesc(getTagValue("desc", eElement));

                listArray.add(objItem);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listArray;
}

private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();

    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

    return nValue.getNodeValue();

}
```

В файле Item.java

```
 public String getTitle() {

    return atitle;
}

public void setTitle(String atitle) {

        this.atitle = atitle;
}
//аналогично и с desc
```

Все хорошо распарсивается, но в случае если встречается item вида

```
<item>
  <title></title>
  <desc>Текст информации</desc>
 </item>
```

То все на этом все ломается и не обрабатывается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне справится с проблемой, когда в тегах ничего нет. Как обрабатывать такие случаи?

Comment: <title><title> - это опечатка? должно быть <title></title> или <title/>

Comment: да, опечатка, сейчас исправлю

Comment: насолько я помню в данном случае item будет null

     Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

или тут проверяйте, что nlList не null (может поможет)

Comment: А с каким сообщением ломается (что именно парсеру не нравиться) ?

Comment: Что выдает longcat в eclipse ? Тут когда запускаю приложение с нормальным title ( где есть информация между тегами), то все нормально выдает, а вот где пустой тег, там к сожалению ломается ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как мне кажется, банально нужно добавить проверку на пустое содержимое элемента xml.

**UPD**

Например так(код для вашего метода getTagValue):

```
if( nValue == null )
    return "";
```

или так:

```
if( nValue.getNodeValue() == null )
    return "";
else
    return nValue.getNodeValue();
```

как точно сами проверьте

Скорее всего падает с NPE(Null Pointer Exception)

Comment: Вот как ее именно организовать ?

Comment: обновил ответ. Попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо! помог первый вариант if( nValue == null )

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использоваться JAXB.
Мне кажется, он осилит справиться, Тем более, что по проще - не надо замарачиваться с кодом) 
Я с таким никогда не сталкивался, интересно, осилит ли он это или нет.
Например тут можно посмотреть: [example](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/200711.mbox/%3C474F52D0.3080408@m3.ath.cx%3E)

Comment: JAXB не включен в android, насколько помню я (можно конечно подтянуть, но там нехилый размер добавится)

Comment: @rasmisha а с чего ты взял, что речь про андройд идет?
я только код на java вижу...

Comment: @Stas0n, метка то стоит.

Comment: Да, разговор про android

Comment: @rasmisha, пардон, не разглядел - кажись спать идти надо)